# Getting private key from file in java

Tags: java, cryptography, private-key

I have private key file with "key" extension.I know that is generated by "Admin-PKI" programm.I must read it as object of PrivateKey type in java to use it for digital signature generation.I tried open it in text editor,but there are not header and footer such as "begin private key" and "end private key".How can i know what algorithm was used to generate the private key?Can i do this without knowing algorithm?

Comment: Do you have a certificate file too?

Comment: yes,it is file with "pem" extension(X509 Certificate).

Comment: What is the "Admin-PKI" program?

Answer (score 0):

the code below loads a file `key.pem`, you will need the bouncycastle library (http://bouncycastle.org/)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.Security;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader;

public class LoadKey {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        KeyPair keyPair = readKeyPair(new File("key.pem"));
    }

    private static KeyPair readKeyPair(File privateKey) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(privateKey);
        PEMReader r = new PEMReader(fileReader);
        try {
            return (KeyPair) r.readObject();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IOException("The private key could not be decrypted", ex);
        } finally {
            r.close();
            fileReader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

compile and run with

```
javac -cp bcprov-jdk16-146.jar:. LoadKey.java
java -cp bcprov-jdk16-146.jar:. -ea LoadKey
```

Comment: Thank You,but my .pem file does not contain Private Key.(I must read it using SignalCOMProvider only...)

Comment: Did you try with its actual extension? Change the name in the code and try.. it may autodetect

Comment: I get this error...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject cannot be cast to java.security.KeyPair

Comment: when i tried this code with .key extension file,function readKeyPair returns null...

Comment: from the error, it seems that your .key file is a X509CertificateObject, are you sure this .key file is a key?

Comment: I get error when try for .pem file.When try for .key,then get null,but no error....When cast .pem to X509Certificate,i see that it contains onli public key,there is no private key(Sorry for my bad english..)

Comment: understood, the error is expected then.. but null on the key file without error whatsoever, don't know what to do, do you mind me deleting the answer?

Comment: in main function i tried this -  System.out.println(keyPair); and get null
Thank You for answers

Comment: the key file is not a PEM, do you know what type it is?

Comment: unfurtunately  i dont know.I know only that it  is private key.How can i know type of it?

Comment: if you are on linux/unix, you can do `file my.key` on the command line and get a diagnostic message

Comment: @user3064723 You could install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), very useful on windows. Contains a posix terminal and you can install the `file` command as well.